# I keep getting an error saying "Failed to evaluate expression Wordpress deployment"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to start up my WordPress website from the Deployment Manager but I can't seem to find an option to do it. I'm only given the option to delete my deployment. I can't see a URL on my WordPress instance, I only see a red exclamation mark that says, "Failed to evaluate expression Wordpress deployment" when I hover above it.

My Compute Engine says I have no VMs available to run. I can only see my website from the deployment manager. I think my website stopped working because I hadn't updated my credit card. I've now updated my credit card but I'm still struggling. [image: Website in Deployment Manager] [image]

Comment: If you waited more than 30 days, Google probably deleted your resources. If that is the case, delete the deployment and start over.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JohnHanley . That's sad to hear considering the amount of time and effort I put into making the website. Do you think there's a way for me to copy the deployment to a new resource?

Comment: Deleted means **gone**. A deployment is not your data, it is the configuration. You might open a support ticket with Google to double-check. Remember the first rule of everything: back it up.

Comment: Just like John Hanley mentions, if the project was created using a Free Tier account and more than 30 days passed it's 100% impossible to recover them. Official documentation reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en#how-to-upgrade). Same recommendation to create a [Support Case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).